# Google OpenId - How to supply email?

Tags: openid

Now a days many people are logged into multiple google accounts. If we know the users email ahead a time can i provide that email to google in the authentication request?

This way we would skip the first screen in the google openid process where they must select which account they want to authorize (when they are logged into multiple accounts) and skip directly to the authorization.

thanks!